# Rails outputting the wrong assets path

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, assets

First here are my dependencies :

```
ruby '2.2.2'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
```

Following [this article](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag), this should work :

```
image_tag("icon")
# => <img alt="Icon" src="/assets/icon" />
```

My server debugged:

```
image_tag("icon")
[2] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fc87e261120>>)> => "<img src=\"/images/icon\" alt=\"Icon\" />"
```

Why is my server outputting `/images/icon` instead of `/assets/icon`. All my images are inside `app/assets/images` and currently not displaying. What did I do wrong?

**Question update**

Adding extension such as `.png` doesn't help still :

```
pry(#<#<Class:0x007f9095686a00>>)> => "<img src=\"/images/icon.png\" alt=\"Icon\" />"
```

Comment: Also provide icon extension (Eg:- **.png**)

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing image extension. Provide extension like:

`image_tag("icon.png")`

Comment: Did you even try this without icon extension and it worked by adding extension?

Comment: its odd doesn't help me its strange